# How to set HTML field security using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, security, csom, html, provider-hosted-app

Is there a way to set the HTML field security using CSOM?
I already found a way to use PowerShell Scripts but i wondering if there is also a way to use CSOM.

PowerShell:

```
$web.ScriptSafeDomains.Add("DomainToAllow.com")
```

I would be grateful for any help.